# Check for the existence of multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating an entry form that I want to only be accessible when three url params are in place: `example.com/entries/new/2011/01/27` If someone tries to access any other url (i.e. `example.com/entries/new` or `example.com/entries/new/2011/`) I want Rails to set an :alert and bounce the user back to the index page.

Currently, I only have this code in my routes.rb `match '/entries/new/:year/:month/:day' => 'entries#new'`. What do I need to do to control the redirection if the proper params aren't in the URL? Would I check for each param in the controller and then perform a `redirect_to`, or is this something I can do from the routes.rb file exclusively? If it's the former, is there an easier way to check that all three params exist other than:

`if params[:year].nil && params[:month].nil && params[:day].nil redirect_to ...`

Comment: You are probably not getting many answers because this is not the normal way of doing things.  Typically, the URL would be example.com/entries/create?date=2011-01-27 or example.com/entries/create?year=2011&month=1&day=27 and you would not deal with all the routing stuff.  You could then use validations for checking the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This route requires the presence of all three parameters:

```
match '/entries/new/:year/:month/:day' => 'entries#new'
```

With only that route, `GET /entries/new` will result in:

```
No route matches "/entries/new"
```

You can redirect from within `routes.rb` like this:

```
  match '/entries' => 'entries#index'
  match '/entries/new/:year/:month/:day' => 'entries#new'
  match "/entries/new/(*other)" => redirect('/entries')
```

The second line matches paths where all three parameters are present. The third line matches all other cases of `/entries/new` using "route globbing", and does the redirect. Requests matched by the third line will not hit `EntriesController#new`.

Note: you may not need the first line if you've already defined a route to `EntriesController#index` -- but watch out for `resources :entries`, which will redefine `index` and `new`.

More info can be found in the guide Rails [Routing From the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). When using date parameters, constraints are a good idea (Section 4.2)